# Using command "chage" for everyone in the group group

Tags: command-line, user-management, groups

How can i use "**chage**" command to change, for example, minimum number of days before password change for *every user in the group*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a one-shot command to do this, so you would need to extract the list of members from the groups database and loop over it - exactly how you choose to do that is up to you but for example

```
#!/bin/bash

group='group'
mindays=28

IFS=, read -a members < <(getent group "$group" | cut -d: -f4)

for logname in "${members[@]}"; do
  echo chage -m "$mindays" "$logname"
done
```

(remove the `echo` once you are satisfied that it will do the right thing).

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much for help, I'm newbie in Ubuntu commands. :)